# Trouble with routing ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to learn about MVC and ASP.NET Core. I have a small project which interacts with a database. I can insert entries into the database, but my routing seems messed up when I try to delete them.

I have an "expense" controller with two delete methods:

```
//GET-delete
//When we do a delete, show the item deleted
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Delete(int? id)
{
    if (id == null || id == 0)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    var obj = _db.Expenses.Find(id);
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return View(obj);
}

//POST-delete
//Interact with the database to delete the row with the desired ID
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken] //only executes if the user is actually logged in.
public IActionResult DeletePost(int? id)
{
    var obj = _db.Expenses.Find(id);
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    _db.Expenses.Remove(obj);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index"); //this calls up the Index action in the same controller, to show the table again
    }
```

My Index view takes me to the Delete view like this:

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Expense" asp-action="Delete" class="btn btn-danger mx-1" asp-route-Id="@expense.Id">Delete expense</a>
```

I can see the entry I want to delete (https://localhost:44388/Expense/Delete/1), but when I click the delete button, I am being directed to https://localhost:44388/Expense/Delete/DeletePost when I should (I think), be sent to https://localhost:44388/Expense/DeletePost/1. The result is that the browser shows an HTTP 405 error.

Delete.cshtml looks like this:

```
@model InAndOut.Models.Expense

<form method="post" action="DeletePost">
    <input asp-for="Id" hidden>
    <div class="border p-3">
    ...html stuff
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-8 text-center row offset-2">
                        <div class="col">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger w-75" value="Delete" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-success w-75">Back</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Startup.cs has the following route definition:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? Shouldn't the submit button in Delete.cshtml be sending the ID to Expense/DeletePost/<id>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your are using ValidateAntiForgeryToken you have to add one to your view

```
<form method="post" action="DeletePost">
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

or remove this attribute from action.

and fix your  DeletePost action, since you submit the whole form, input parameter should be the whole model

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken] 
public IActionResult DeletePost(Expense model)
{
    var id=model.Id;
   ....
    
}
```

Comment: Removing the `[ValidateAntiForgerToken]` or adding `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` to the Delete view AND changing the form action from `action="DeletePost"` to `action="/Expense/DeletePost"` seems to have done the trick.

I'm just learning, but I think `<input asp-for="Id" hidden>` in Delete.cshtml is what allows me to define the DeletePost method with "(int? id)" instead of an object.

Comment: @StackExchangeGuy Thanks for a feedback.  Yes, you are right it maybe working when you use just id. But I am an old school  and prefer to use the whole model  as an input parameter when I am submitting a form

Comment: @StackExchangeGuy it allows to prevent misspelling  errors too.